# Should I fix broken links through an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, broken-link

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632825/5798798) while looking into HTML5's `canvas` and noticed that the link was broken. I did a little looking around and noticed that the link had slightly changed, so I did a suggested edit on the answer with the correct link.

My [edit was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15642494), however [Koby Douek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694368/koby-douek) rejected the edit with:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I am wondering what the reason for this would be and whether suggested edits should be used to fix broken links? I would be interested in hearing why this user rejected the edit as they may have a valid point.

According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), these points should be when you edit a post:

- To fix grammar and spelling mistakes To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
- To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
- To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
- To add related resources or hyperlinks

I believe my edit came under the last point, to add related resources or hyperlinks.

Comment: You already gave an correct edit comment with *fixed link - was broken*. The only thing I can say that it might not got noticed so maybe a longer comment could have helped here. But that is all you can do.

Answer (score 6):

If you can update a broken link, do it. It keeps the value of the answer without changing any of its meaning. The community (3/4 reviewers) rightfully approved your edit, which falls under the categories

- (...) add updates as the post ages
- To add related resources or hyperlinks

Nobody except for the user who rejected it can tell you why exactly they did, but the reason they picked certainly doesn't make any sense. Surely the answerer themselves would prefer to have a valid link to the same article on their own website in their answer instead of a broken one.

I'd suggest you not to worry about it, since you didn't do anything wrong. Stuff like this will always happen (which is also the reason why it takes more than one reviewer to approve or reject a suggested edit).