# Should link rot fix edits be approved, even if the existing link redirects?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, broken-link

I see a few suggested edits with a comment like '*fix link rot*', and I tried navigating to the former URL. It redirected to the new URL. Bearing in mind that "*Edits are expected to be substantial*"<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)</sup> enough to warrant a change (and not waste time of the reviewers), should a URL that redirects be updated? I know that eventually the old URL might be disabled.

I did find the related post [*Should I fix broken links through an edit?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345983/1575353) which would apply here **except** that in this case the URL redirects...

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing</sub>

Comment: Fwiw, a redirecting link is a way to always link to the docs of the newest version of boost, like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/hash.html

Comment: I think it's an improvement to remove redirect pages if they require the user to manually click to go to the page they actually want [(e.g., the MSDN "Content Moved" page)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511486(v=MSDN.10).aspx#patterns). I'm neutral on the cases where the links auto-redirect I guess. Also as a general "is this edit substantial enough" metric, remember that saying a suggested edit is too minor is probably the same as saying "it's alright for the post to stay that way forever" unless somebody gets pinged in chat.

Answer (score 37):

Personally, I don't see the harm in it.  The concern is that redirects will eventually break, and if a more permanent resource exists, then the user should be pointed to that.

I would caution you though, if the entire answer hinges on whether or not that link is accessible...that answer may be a good candidate to remove outright.  We don't want to be in the business of forcefully maintaining links in that fashion, specifically because of this scenario.

Comment: Or rather than removing, quoting (some of the) link's content into the answer.